# How to concisely output string only if string has value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to know if there is a way to output a string only if the value isn't `nil` but to it without repeating the item.

In other words I want to do the following:

`<%= MyClass.thing.stuff.more_stuff if !MyClass.thing.stuff.more_stuff.blank?  %>`

But without having to repeat the whole thing twice. Not even sure if it's possible but I couldn't figure out the right terms to Google.

Comment: If `MyClass.thing.stuff.more_stuff` is nil so that `<%= MyClass.thing.stuff.more_stuff %>` will returns nil too. And as result it won't print any output in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= MyClass.thing.stuff.more_stuff %>
```

will work. Because an outputted nil will turn into an empty string and thus no output in an erb template.

So will `presence` if you want something more complicated

```
<%= MyClass.thing.stuff.more_stuff.presence %>
```

Docs: http://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence